# Kurento Media Server Throwing " Unexpected error while processing method: Factory 'PlayerEndPoint'' not found"

Tags: json-rpc, kurento

I am Very new to Kurento. I went through its json-rpc documentation from this link.

http://www.kurento.org/docs/5.0.3/mastering/kurento_protocol.html

1) I have installed a local kurento server which runs on the port 8888.
2) I used a tool called wscat to establish a connection to the kurento-websocket.
3) I tried to connect to the kurento-server with below command

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8888/kurento
```

After that i got the connected prompt from the server.

From the above kurento protocol documentation link. I have used the below request json

```
   {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "create",
  "params": {
    "type": "PlayerEndPoint",
    "creationParams": {
      "pipeline": "6829986",
      "uri": "http://host/app/video.mp4"
    },
    "sessionId": "c93e5bf0-4fd0-4888-9411-765ff5d89b93"
  }
}
```

But according to the docs the response which i should get after sending this request is like this.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": {
    "value": "442352747",
    "sessionId": "c93e5bf0-4fd0-4888-9411-765ff5d89b93"
  }
}
```

But i am getting

```
{
 "error":
          {"code":-32603,
           "message":"Unexpected error while processing method: Factory  PlayerEndPoint not found"         
          },
 "id":1,
 "jsonrpc":"2.0"
}
```

If i am not wrong the above request-json is used to create a new media pipeline for player end point which is used to stream http://host/app/video.mp4.

Is there any problem in my request-json object or do i have to do something before giving this request.

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems. The first is that `PlayerEndpoint` is not correctly spelled (note the lower case "p" `PlayerEnd-p-oint`). The second is that you need to first to create a `MediaPipeline` before you can create a `PlayerEndpoint` or any other media element.

If you are new to Kurento, my recommendation is that you should try to use the official Kurento client implementations (currently available in Java and JavaScript). If you want to create your very own Kurento client, you'll need to read carefully the documentation because there are a lot of details you'll need to manage (e.g. the distributed garbage collector, the WebSocket reconnection mechanisms, etc.)

Comment: the docs on json-rpc for kurento is not useful. can you suggest me any other resources where i can read it.

Comment: @sathyaNarrayanan If you need to know which methods are exposed through the Kurento Protocol, you will have to look at the .kmd files in different github projects (basically [kms-core](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-core/tree/master/src/server/interface), [kms-elements](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements/tree/master/src/server/interface) and [kms-filters](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/tree/master/src/server/interface))